# android zoomable and scrollable board game

Tags: 2d, android, rendering

I'm developing a Android board game and have a question regarding creating a board that is zoomable and scrollable. The board contains a static background, characters (players) and  the actual "level" which is drawn using tiles.

My solutions is to have a collection of elements (tiles, figures, all game elements - all have x,y coordinates and width + height), a camera and a renderer that draws the collection according to cameraX,cameraY, cameraWidth and cameraHeight. So if a user would scroll to the right, the camera would just set the cameraX appropriately - and the surface is scrollable. And if a user would zoom in/out the renderer would just scale every element image appropriately.

Example code for the renderer with scrollable surface and zoom in/out

```
    protected function draw(Canvas c){
      Collection elements = collection.getElements(cameraX,cameraY,cameraWidth,cameraHeight);
      if(elements.size() > 0) {
         for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
              elements.get(i).drawElement(c);
         }
      }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    // element class drawElement function
    protected drawElement function(Canvas c) {
        if(this.image != null) {            
          int w = this.width;
          int h = this.height;
          if(this.zoomFactor < 1) {
             w*=this.zoomFactor;
             h*=this.zoomFactor;
          }
          c.drawBitmap(this.image,this.x,this.y,w,h);
        }
    }
```

- Is this the best solutions?
- Could it be achived somehow else?
- Could scrolling be achived using a ScrollView?

I dont wanna use any engine, because this is for a school project.

Comment: first `c.drawBitmap(...)` should be changed to `c.drawBitmap(this.image,(this.x - camera.x) / camera.width, (this.y - camera.y) / camera.height,w,h)` and besides that, it seems in that code you are relying on cpu power too much, I think it would be faster if you try opengl and gpu power. besides that you code should work fine.

Comment: The code i wrote is basicly just a an example, so it is not the actual code. The game isn't really that demanding (gpu wise) it's almost a turn based game with animations..  that's why i chose android canvas over opengl. If the game wont be as responsive as i want it to be i will switch to opengl.

Answer (score 1):

Good logic but use Matricies with scale transformations to implement zoom, do not try and calculate it everywhere yourself.

That way you could write the following code:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.setMatrix(myMapMatrix);

// TODO write the rest of the drawing code here using map co-ordinates

canvas.restore();
```

Where myMapMatrix is the matrix that lets you go from the screen viewport to the board game map. And if you get the inverse matrix then you can transform a map co-ordinate into a screen co-ordinate. I know because this is the way that I am currently doing it in my game.

I will leave how to create the Matrix as an exercise for you but let me give you [a hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#preScale%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29).